# NWPusher in swift Library

Tags: ios, swift

I need to use NWPusher which to be in swift (without using objective c files)? I know about bridging the objective c files in swift but I prefer in swift?

Comment: Bridging headers make it easy.  The only thing more native Swift than that would be for you to reimplement the whole sourcebase in Swift.  Good luck with that!

Comment: @Michale yes Michael that is easy but i asking if we use swift library means task gone be more easy than the bridging the header... do you know any library like NWPusher in swift